# StreamGobbler - Thread to accept input into it? Java

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, output

Using an self-edited `StreamGobbler` to run a php script, 
I am trying to input commands into the script while it is running...

StreamGobbler.java

```
private class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
    InputStream is;
    OutputStream os;
    String line;
    PMRunnerPro main;

    public StreamGobbler(InputStream is, OutputStream os, PMRunnerPro main) {
        this.is = is;
        this.os = os;
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));


            line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null && ! line.trim().equals("--EOF--")) {
                if (main.sSendNeeded) {
                    System.out.println("Sent");
                    writer.write(main.sCommand + "\n");

                    main.sSendNeeded = false;
                    main.sCommand = "";
                }
                main.outputBox.setText(main.outputBox.getText() + (line + "\n"));
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            writer.flush();

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            main.sRunning = false;
        }

        System.out.println("Over");
        main.sRunning = false;
    }
}
```

The command is sent to the script only when there is an output from the script.

I want the Thread to continuously check if there is any command to send to the script and then do so if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your intentions correctly...

Since you using blocking I/O, you need two threads for what you want:

- 1st thread will read script output, as you do now. Once output available, it will be shown in textarea;
- 2nd thread will read input from queue and forward it to script.

Here's code draft (notice that you may want to add synchronization between input and output workers, so input worker won't be able to send new command to script until previous command produces output from script, but that's up to you):

```
class InputWorker implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null && ! line.trim().equals("--EOF--")) {
                // show script output
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            //
        }
    }
}

class OutputWorker implements Runnable {
    final BlockingQueue<String> commandQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>();

    public void sendCommand(String command) {
        commandQueue.add(command);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

            while (true) {
                String command = commandQueue.take();
                if ("EXIT".equals(command)) { return; }
                writer.write(command);
                writer.flush();
            }

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            //
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could u explain more on how i could use the above code with my current one?  My application contains a textbox to write commands, once the button is pressed, the command would be written in `sCommand`, also making `sSendNeeded` to true. Then the thread would notice that `sSendNeeded` is true and would then write `sCommand`

Comment: @junyi00 instead of writing value to `sCommand`, call `inputFromElsewhere`.

Comment: @junyi00 actually, now I understand better what you need, there's no need for communication between threads: output thread should be like in your OP, just w/o checks for input. Input thread should use queue as shown above to get data from operator and passing it to script.

Comment: @junyi00 I've updated answer with more relevant code, I think.

Comment: Srry, i rarely use Runnable type and this is my first time creating such an application. Could u explain how i could implement the above code into the thread above?

Comment: Proper explaination won't fit in comments here :) Please, read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/